# Will a 128GB SDXC work on a 64GB compatible sd card slot?

Tags: compatibility, tablet, lenovo-laptop, micro-sd-card, memory-card

I'm not quite sure if this was the correct board for this topic. But I had been searching for an answer and found no luck in with regard to this specific question..

I'm looking to buy a Lenovo Miix 3-10 (80HV0025PH) Hybrid Windows tablet for school. As it only comes in 64GB eMMC (other options are only 32GB), I am thinking that it would not be enough storage space for me, as this will be my main and only computer. This [website](http://www.villman.com/Product-Detail/Lenovo_Miix_3_80HV0025PH), [the official shop site](http://shop.lenovo.com/gb/en/tablets/lenovo/miix-series/lenovo-miix3-10-inch/#tab-features) and some other sources state that I can expand the storage with an sd card of upto another 64GB. Normally I would be satisfied with this setup but if I have the option to put a 128GB card then why not?

The main question is if it can support 64GB then it must mean it's a SDXC compatible card slot, so in turn it should (?) be able to make use of the 128GB card. I can't afford to physically test this myself since there is a no refunds policy if I willingly buy the 128GB card knowing about the 64GB limit of the device (I'm gonna be buying from the same store.

Anyone here with a similar device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, yes. [This page](https://www.sdcard.org/consumers/compatibility/) is the official compatibility chart from the SD association. [Your device](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/tablets/lenovo/miix-series/miix-3-10-inch/) states:

> With a Micro-SD slot, you can add up to 64GB of external storage to your 2-in-1 tablet...

For it to support 64GB, it must support `SDXC` with ExFat, as `SDHC` supports only up to 32GB.

***However*** - The release date of the Lenovo Miix 3-10 was [February 2015](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/lenovo-miix-3-2403). 128GB MicroSDXC cards were released [early 2014](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroSD).

This means there was around 1 year for MicroSDXC cards of 128GB capacity to be released and tested. The fact the site is stating it will only support up to 64GB this long after 128GB cards were released, I would suggest it is not fully supported and you won't get the full amount of space available. I would therefore recommend going for a 64GB you can be certain will work.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases what is officially supported and what works are not the same, but the only way to know for sure is to try, which can be a rather expensive method if it does not work. *i.e.* my phone officially supports only 32GB micro-SD, but is widely reported to work fine with 64; personally I went with 32 not so much due to the "officially supported status" as the fact that I don't really do enough with the phone to stress the 32 GB storage and at the time 64 was a large premium in price/GB.

If you can find a user group or similar of folks with your proposed computer you might get reports of what actually works (who knows, could be 256 GB works fine, and those are getting less obnoxiously priced, while the 512 GB and 1TB cards have the large $/GB premium now.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late to post this perhaps - but yes, the Miix 3 -10 can function with a 128GB SD Card - I am now using a Samsung 128GB SD Card as the documents drive disk for my Miix.

Add-on - I used a 200GB SD Card from Sandisk and managed to use 179GB from it. The other 20GB was partition space. Still - for those who need a bump in memory space - this is an improvement from the 64GB advertised as the maximum SD card size supported for this machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The "other 20GB" is due mostly to the fact that "GB" on an SD card means 1,000,000,000 while "GB" to Windows means 1024 cubed. You don't lose 20 GB out of 200 to partitioning or file system overhead! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question due to the title but I am using a different device.

I too was curious if a device that supports 64GB SDXC cards might support a 128GB SDXC card.

My particular device is a Campark Action Cam in which the specifications state it supports 64GB micro-SD cards.  Since that implies it supports SDXC I thought I would give a 128GB card a try.

And indeed it does work.  More exactly it reports 119GB free after a format and can record and playback video.   I placed the camera in loop record mode and will report back on how it behaves as the card fills up beyond 64GB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the 128gb MicroSD works fine. In addition I am using a 128GB USB to improve the storage. Both work well together. In essence you will get 64gb internal, 128gb microsd and 128gb USB

Ranbir

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it should work fine... but be aware that filesystem may suppot only 64GB of that 128. In the worst scenario, you would have to create partition that would only have half of whole size, but that shouldn't be necessary in most of cases.

Please note, that chances that whole 128GB would work are ... small.

Comment: by file system does that mean FAT32, NTFS, exFAT and the likes?

Comment: yes and no... FAT32 supports up to 32 (127GB - depending on drivers) (not a single byte more), exFAT depending on version supports up to <no limit>?, NTFS should support 128GB without any problem... but... it's not only matter of file system itself, but file system driver... some of them have their own limitations.

Comment: FAT32 supports up to 2^32 sectors. With 512-byte sectors, that means 2 TiB. So sorry, but this answer is just plain wrong. The card reader is also not concerned with filesystems at all.

Comment: As I said... its highly driver dependable... on Windows 2000, FAT32 supported only up to 32GB for example. I am giving real life limitations, not some theoretical ones.

Comment: There is no such limit on Windows 2000. It will refuse to *create* FAT32 filesystems larger than 32 GiB. This is an artificial limit to promote NTFS. FAT32 is still fully usable, even today.

Comment: As I said, most of those limits are arificial.